# Polynomial Regression Degree Increasing Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to predict Boston Housing prices. When I choose polynomial regression degree 1 or 2, R2 score is OK. But 3rd degree decreases R2 score.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston_dataset = load_boston()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(boston_dataset.data, columns = boston_dataset.feature_names)
dataset['MEDV'] = boston_dataset.target

X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values.reshape(-1,1)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)   # <-- Tuning to 3
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly, y_train)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y_train)

y_pred = lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_test))

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print('Prediction Score is: ', r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output (degree=2):

```
Prediction Score is:  0.6903318065831567
```

Output (degree=3):

```
Prediction Score is:  -12898.308114085281
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called overfitting the model.What you are doing is fitting the model perfectly on the training set that will lead to high variance.When you fit your hypothesis well on the training set it will then fail on the test set. You can check your r2_score for your training set using `r2_score(X_train,y_train)`. It will be high. You need to balance the trade-off between bias and variance.

You can try other regression models like lasso and ridge and can play with their alpha value in case you are looking for a high r2_score. For better understanding, I am putting up an image that will show how hypothesis line gets affected on increasing the degree of the polynomial.
[image]

Comment: If you add few test observations to the plot, will give a better idea of failing on the test set.